# How to get the message from temporary Queue in Different session

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

i am new to jms and activemq. i produce one message to one static queue in activemq and  get  reply back to temporary queue using getJMSReplyTo. the code is following

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new  ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

    // Create a Connection
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    // Create a Session
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


    // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
    Destination destination = (Destination)   session.createQueue("PostWithParameter_Queue");

    // Create a MessageConsumer from the Session to the Topic or Queue
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination);
    //consumer.setMessageListener(new StaticQueueListener());
    // Wait for a message
    Message message = (Message) consumer.receive();
    MessageConsumer consumer1 = session.createConsumer(message.getJMSReplyTo());
    consumer1.setMessageListener(new ReplyHandler()); 
    consumer.close();
    session.close();
```

My Reply Handler follows

```
@Override
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    try
    {

        System.out.println(message.getStringProperty("status"));
    }
    catch (JMSException e) 
    {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now i am getting the result from temporary queue. because its in the same session.
my question is i want to get the message from temporary queue  in differesnt session using temporary queue name. if i want to get the message from temporary queue in different client  using temporary queue name how i will do that ? .

Comment: Your listener can work with any JMS session that you provide,it doesn't have to be the same session as the one that you placed the message with.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would set the reply-to jms header, and then wherever you consume the message (eg, certainly in a different session..) you can pull out that JMSReplyTo header which would be the temp destination and just reply to that.

You should check the ActiveMQ wiki:

http://activemq.apache.org/how-should-i-implement-request-response-with-jms.html

Comment: hii thnks for the reply. in that link what they do is , in client side they create a messagelistner and produce the message in same thread or session to ativemq. what i want is messagelistner(consume message) in different thread and consume message. how to achieve that..? waiting for ur reply..

Answer (score 0):

Your listener can work with any JMS session that you provide,it doesn't have to be the same session as the one that you placed the message with.

Comment: i agreed with u.but when i tried to consume the message with tempQueue name it creating one queue with that name.its not consuming the message.