# How to get Message without creating Queue in Activemq

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, messaging

i am new to activemq. i created one queue and produce one message to that queue from one client. i want to consume that message from another client. for consume the message the code follows

```
ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

    // Create a Connection
    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    // Create a Session
    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);


    // Create the destination (Topic or Queue)
    Destination destination = (Destination) session.createQueue("StaticQueueName");

     MessageConsumer consumer= session.createConsumer(destination);
     Message message = (Message) consumer.receive();
     System.out.println(message.getStringProperty("status"));
      if (message instanceof TextMessage) {
         TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) message;
         Text = textMessage.getText();
         System.out.println("Received: " + Text);
     } else {
         System.out.println("Received: " + message);
     }
```

if we have already knew the queue name then no need to create.i metioning below code.

```
 Destination destination = (Destination) session.createQueue("StaticQueueName");
```

so is there any method available if we know the queue name before.so using that queue name we can access the message like getqueue("queue name") instead of create the queue.

Answer (score 2):

If such a queue already exists, then no other queue will be created, the same will be given to you. It will not get 'overridden'.

Comment: please check this link.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19705413/how-to-get-the-message-from-temporary-queue-in-different-session/19708727?noredirect=1#19708727

Answer (score 1):

```
QueueReceiver receiver= session.createReceiver(queueName);
receiver.setMessageListener(this);
```

If you know the `queueName` than just create a `receiver` it will get the message from the queue.